# How can I make the angles of my polar coordinates relate to exposure proportions in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, polar-coordinates

Suppose I have the following data in R:

```
mydata <- data.frame(Group=1:5, Profit=seq(60, 100, by=10), 
Count=seq(50000, 10000, by=-10000))
```

I can plot a bar chart showing the Profit by Group:

```
r1 <- ggplot(data=mydata, aes(x=Group, y=Profit, fill=Group))
r1 + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  scale_fill_gradient(low="khaki", high="turquoise4") +
  labs(title="Group 5 is the most profitable segment")
```

I can also plot a pie chart showing the proportion of exposure (Count) by Group:

```
r2 <- ggplot(data=mydata, aes(x="", y=Count, fill=Group))
r2 + 
  geom_bar(width=1, stat="identity") +
  scale_fill_gradient(low="khaki", high="turquoise4") +
  coord_polar(theta="y", start=0) +
  labs(title="We have significant exposure in lower Groups")
```

What I'd like to do is combine the above so that the angle of the pie relates to the exposure proportions for each Group level as it is in r2, but also to increase/decrease the size of each "slice" (i.e. the radius) according to the profit for each Group level in r1.

Any help gratefully received.

Thanks

Comment: This type of graphic is sometimes known as a spie plot apparently. Or just "that Florence Nightingale one".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
mydata %>%
  mutate(end_count = cumsum(Count),  # or add "/sum(Count)" to make it "out of 100%"
         start_count = lag(end_count, default = 0)) %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = start_count, xmax = end_count,
                ymin = 0, ymax = Profit, fill=Group)) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low="khaki", high="turquoise4") +
  coord_polar(theta="x", start=0) +
  labs(title="We have significant exposure in lower Groups")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, that worked. I did it a similar, albeit slightly different way:

Comment: mydata$Exposure_pct <- mydata$Count / sum(mydata$Count)
    mydata$Cumulative_Exposure_pct <- cumsum(mydata$Exposure_pct)
    mydata$Profit_pct <- mydata$Profit / sum(mydata$Profit)
    mydata$mid_point <- mydata$Cumulative_Exposure_pct - 0.5*mydata$Exposure_pct

    s <- ggplot(data=mydata, aes(x=mid_point, y=Profit, fill=Group))
    s + 
      geom_bar(width=mydata$Exposure_pct, stat="identity") +
      scale_fill_gradient(low="khaki", high="turquoise4") +
      coord_polar(theta="x", start=0)